# Filter same-type DataFrame by value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` to essentially associate `Type1` and `Type2` and `df[t1][t2]` always returns a state of type `State`. The content of the `DataFrame` suggests that I should just be using a `numpy` array, but I need to be able to index it like a dictionary, that is why I am using a `DataFrame`. If there is a better way to design this please let me know.

I am trying to collect a list of all `type1,type2` combinations where their value in the `df` matches a particular state. I can filter a single row:

```
row = df[type1]
row[row == state]
```

But how can I filter the entire `DataFrame`?

Comment: Is possible add some data sample with expected output?

Comment: try this, df[df['type1']==state]

Comment: @MohamedThasinah that is *exactly* the example of filtering *one* row, not the entire `DataFrame.`

Comment: @jezrael a list of the index,column combination that matches the filter, or a masked `DataFrame` that would easily allow building such list.

Comment: @dabadaba- Do you need to check is state present in all the rows instead of one column?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah I need to check single cell `df[t1][t2]` and extract `(t1, t2)` as a matching result. And do that for the entire `df` and get a list of all `(type1, type2)` matching said state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  suggest change format to `MultiTndex Series` :

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  8  8  3
1  7  7  0
2  4  2  5

a = df.stack()
print (a)
0  A    8
   B    8
   C    3
1  A    7
   B    7
   C    0
2  A    4
   B    2
   C    5
dtype: int32

b = a[a == 8].index.remove_unused_levels().tolist()
print (b)
[(0, 'A'), (0, 'B')]
```

EDIT:

For better performance is possible use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for indices of matched values and then `zip` indexed index and columns names to tuples:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  8  8  3
1  7  7  0
2  4  2  5

a =  np.where(df == 8)
print (a)
(array([0, 0], dtype=int64), array([0, 1], dtype=int64))

b = list(zip(df.index[a[0]], df.columns[a[1]]))
print (b)
[(0, 'A'), (0, 'B')]
```

Comment: Would accessing the state for `t1,t2` still be `O(1)` that way?

Comment: @dabadaba - Hard question for me. But maybe is possible create `MultiIndex Series` some other way as `unstack`, it depends what are input data

Comment: it would be a very important requirement. Also, I am not too keen about having the second index repeated all over again for every first index, since my `DataFrame`s are usually pretty large.

Comment: @dabadaba - I think I understand, added `np.where` solution for it